# Display two element classes after hover

Tags: css

```
.element:hover .element-add, .element-add2 {
    display: block;
}
```

How to display element-add and element-add2 after .element is hovered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add each seperately:

```
.element:hover .element-add, .element:hover .element-add2 {
    display: block;
}
```